# Why do IDEs not have pause buttons built into them?

Tags: ide, cpu-architecture, processor

I would guess this answer could be found somewhere, but I am struggling to communicate with Google tonight.

I simply was thinking, there is a play and stop, why not a pause button?

It would equally be nice when I need to utilize my computer for other processor intensive tasks.

Comment: The internal state of an application would have to be saved somewhere, so the application would restart properly.  You could code your application such that it can be paused (see some games), but most IDE platforms weren't designed to host long-running CPU-intensive jobs.

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent of a Unix shell's job control?  When you hit control-z to send SIGTSTP (terminal-stop) to a process, it goes to sleep (but still exists and a process), and the shell will let you `bg` (start it running again but in the background), or `fg` (put it back running in the foreground).  That *won't* free any memory it's allocated (unlike @GilbertLeBlanc's suggestion of using some kind of process checkpointing to dump process state to disk.)  But will stop it using CPU time until you resume, and the kernel can page out its dirty memory if there's enough swap.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. I had an idea, but I imagined there was someone out there that just knew all about this specific subject.